# difference between linking and including header file

Tags: gcc, dynamic-linking

Are these two equivalent or different (in what sense)?

**myfile1.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    //some code here which uses math library
```

and compiling normally using `gcc`

```
$gcc myfile1.c
```

**myfile2.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    //some code here which uses math library
```

but compiling this using the following statement

```
$gcc myfile2.c -lm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrote a program to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main() {
    double f = 0.5;
    printf("%f", sqrt(f));
}
```

both commands produce 8432 byte files which are identical on my machine.

So I guess in both cases, `libm` is dynamically-linked, I guess libs will be statically linked if only an archive file(*.a) is found, instead of the typical (*.so) shared libraries